# Emmet wrap with abbreviation input+label

Tags: html, forms, emmet

What's the abbreviation to produce the following code after selecting the lines below :

```
radio1
radio2
radio3
```

to produce:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radioGroup">
<label for="radio1">radio1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radioGroup">
<label for="radio2">radio2</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radioGroup">
<label for="radio3">radio3</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it *is* [Wrap With Abbreviation](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/) but slightly different than has been suggested

Select all lines then hit the keycombo (below) and type:

`(input[type=radio id=$# name=radioGroup]+label[for=$#]{$#})*{}`

The key is the `*` which wraps each line you've selected and the `{}` wraps the content. The `$#` [Controls output position](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#controlling-output-position).

Keycombos - if you're using Sublime Text:

Ctrl + w (macOS - must also disable Vintegous)

Ctrl + Shift + G (windows)

Comment: Of course `#` doesn't mean anything special to Emmet, but `$#` does: See [Controlling output position](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#controlling-output-position). And actually this was an issue ([#292](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim/issues/292)) with emmet-vim which is now resolved. Although I get the same issue using [live editor](http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#controlling-output-position) but seems including `{}` at end produces the right result: `(input[type='radio'][id="$#"][name="radioGroup"]+label[for="‌​$#"]{$#})*{}`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go man...

```
(input[type='radio'][id="radio$"][name="radioGroup"]+label[for="radio$"]{radio$})*3
```

Comment: tanx BUT _Wrap with abbreviation_ is different from _abbreviation expansion_. your abbreviation is right but only if i literally type it and expand it. My question is for a tentative and more general situation. imean i type options that here are : radio1, radio2 and radio3; select them all and then enter the abbreviation. i want that. i replace `radio$` of your abbreviation with `$#` and deleting `3` i.e : `(input[type='radio'][id="$#"][name="radioGroup"]+label[for="$#"]{$#})*`. but with no success and unwanted results!